# Редирект списка категорий с удалением подкатегории

Tags: php, .htaccess

Существуют ссылки типа:

```
Сайт.ру/rus/mos/phone/nexus/ 
Сайт.ру/rus/spb/watch/tissot/
```

и т.д.

Нужен редирект 301 без региональной привязки:

```
Сайт.ру/phone/nexus/
Сайт.ру/watch/tissot/
```

Возможно ли сделать шаблон подстановки (универсальное правило)?
Так как таких категорий много.

Comment: можно сделать...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^cat1/subcat2/(.*)   $1  [R=301,L]
```

**Update**

Мда.
Похоже на тот случай, когда разработчик фронтэнда решил попрактиковаться в мод_реврайте.

Что касается подстановки `/rus/mos/phone/nexus/ -> /phone/nexus/` и `/rus/spb/watch/tissot/ -> /watch/tissot/`, то на мой взгляд не получится сделать одного универсального правила.

Дело в том, что из-за внутреннего устройства `мod_rewrite` в этом случае не получится применить универсальный шаблон типа `/\w+/\w+(.*)`, который бы "превращал" `/rus/mos/phone/nexus/` в `/phone/nexus/` с последующим переходом на ссылку [http://cайт.ру/phone/nexus/](http://c%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/phone/nexus/), потому как после первого преобразования пути по указанному шаблону, процесс применения шаблона повторится уже для пути `/phone/nexus/`, что приведет к полному урезанию пути до "нуля", и в итоге запрос будет переадресован на корень сайта.

Поэтому без кастомизированных шаблонов не обойтись.

```
RewriteRule  ^rus/spb/(.*)  $1 [R=301,L]
```

Хотя я не исключаю тут какой-нибудь лайфхак, про который я просто не в курсе.

Comment: @sander добавьте этот комментарий в ваш вопрос и по возможности пару реальных примеров путей. Также покажите все правила `RewriteRule` из вашего файла. Я тестировал свой ответ - он работает, единственное, что нужно добавить в начале `RewriteBase /` для надежности.

Comment: Как просили, более подробно

Comment: @sander добавил в апдейт